# How to clear history and run all migrations from the beginning?

Tags: python, migration, alembic

How I can clear history using alembic?  I couldn't find this option in `alembic history`.  I want to run from the first migration rather than the last applied.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to start with a fresh database, just drop the database, create a new one, then run the migrations.  For example, with PostgreSQL:

```
$ dropdb my_db
$ createdb my_db
$ alembic upgrade head
```

Now you have a blank database with all the migrations applied.

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
alembic downgrade base
```

This command will undo all migrations.

([source](https://anagraph.io/en/articles/alembic_in_2021/))

Answer (score 8):

In latest version of alembic (0.7.6) you can use the [**stamp**](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/commands.html#alembic.command.stamp) command:

```
alembic stamp base
```

This command will clear migration history, but it won't revert any applied migrations.

Comment: -1; this doesn't do what the question asked for at all. This will make Alembic *think* that no migrations have been run, but won't actually undo any migrations that actually have been run, most likely causing any subsequent `upgrade` command to fail (as it'll be trying to create tables that already exist).

Comment: @MarkAmery The question doesn't explicitly state that migrations must be undone. I think there are two possible interpretations and both answers are equally valid.

Answer (score 8):

Alembic is keeping track of the migrations in the `alembic_version` table on your database.

Simply drop the table to start from scratch using the following command:
`DROP TABLE alembic_version;`

And then try to run your migration again!